# RadioButton selection jumps is auto selected on other Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have a custom listView that is populated by Excel Sheet using `jXl` library.
Everything works fine but when I select one or more ListView Item, automatically after 8-9 entries my selection is also selected on other ListView Item.. for example if `radioButton1` is selected at index `0` now If I scroll down I see `radioButton1` is selected at index `8`.
Here is my code:
**CustomListView**

```
public class CustomListView extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel> {

    Context context;
    private List<ListModel> studentsList;
    ListModel listModel;
    TextView name, date;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton presentRDOButton, absentRDOButton, leaveRDOButton;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static List<ListModel> attenList = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
    final JExcelClass jXl = new JExcelClass();
    boolean flagPres = true;
    boolean flagAbsen = true;
    boolean flagLeave = true;

    public AttendanceCustomListView(Context context, int resource,
            List<ListModel> studentsList) {
        super(context, resource, studentsList);
        this.context = context;
        this.studentsList = studentsList;
    }

private class ViewHolder {
        TextView name, date;
        RadioGroup radioGroup;
        RadioButton presentRDOButton, absentRDOButton, leaveRDOButton;
    }
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
        final int pos = position + 1;

        // inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        // .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_content, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // initialization here
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameListTV);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTV);
            holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.attendanceRDG);
            holder.presentRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.presentRDO);
            holder.absentRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.absentRDO);
            holder.leaveRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.leaveRDO);
            holder.radioGroup
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                int checkedId) {
                            int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();

                           studentsList.get(getPosition). //problem here

                           switch (checkedId) {
                            case R.id.presentRDO:
                               //code goes here
                                 break;
                                    }

                }
            });
```

and 
**CustomClass**

```
public class CustomClass extends Activity {

    ListView listView;
    List<ListModel> listModel;
CustomListView attendanceCustomListView;
    JExcelClass jXl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_listview);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listModel = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
        jXl = new JExcelClass();
        List<String> abc = jXl.readExcelSheet("test.xls");
        String date = this.getDate();
        for (String temp : abc) {
            listModel.add(new ListModel(temp, date));
        }
        attendanceCustomListView = new AttendanceCustomListView(this,
                R.layout.layout_list_content, listModel);
        listView.setAdapter(attendanceCustomListView);
    }
}
```

Please let me know If some more information is needed. Thanks.

**Updated the Code**
Now my problem is how to set the `RadioButton` through `RadioGroup`?

Comment: try remove this : if (convertView == null)

Comment: @mmlooloo by removing things even get worse.

Comment: what happend when you removed that? i think this is a first step to solve your problem, because this problem caused by recycling of convertView, so first step is not allowing it to use recycled view!

Comment: Is your views recycling?

Comment: @Amsheer yes the view is recycling.

Comment: Just override onscrolllistener and save your views state there.

Comment: @Amsheer Could you please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! at last i got my answer! 
Basically all i needed was to add 3 `static final` variables and use them for saving the state of the radioButton clicked.
Please follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392511/how-to-handle-oncheckedchangelistener-for-a-radiogroup-in-a-custom-listview-adap/9484222#9484222), this is the most simple answer all over the internet.
Thanks @hrishitiwari for pointing to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you do in OnCheckChanged? I had a similar issue and in my case, it was because I was using the position from

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

to update the data onCheckChanged.

What eventually solved it for me, is 
1. Using the [ViewHolder pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html).
2. When updating the data onCheckChanged, the position I used for data.get(NewPosition).set...(true) was not the position from the getview, rather from :

```
int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();
```

The getTag(); comes from using the Viewholder pattern and group comes from:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();//do this

                switch (checkedId) {
                  case R.id.presentRDO:
                     //some code here....

                      studentsList.get(getPosition).setPresent(true);//do this
                  break;
                 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Do this:

```
  if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_content, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                // initialization here
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameListTV);
                holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTV);
                holder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.attendanceRDG);
                holder.presentRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.presentRDO);
                holder.absentRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.absentRDO);
                holder.leaveRDOButton = (RadioButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.leaveRDO);
                 convertView.setTag(R.id.attendanceRDG, holder.radioGroup);//do for all           views

                    }

                } else {

                    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
                }

                  holder.radioGroup.setTag(position);//Similarly for all elements


                   holder.radioGroup
                        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group,
                                    int checkedId) {
                                int getPosition = (Integer) group.getTag();

                               studentsList.get(getPosition). //problem here

                               switch (checkedId) {
                                case R.id.presentRDO:
                                   //code goes here
                                     break;
                                        }

                });
```

Comment: this gives `nullpointerexception` at this line `int getPosition= (Integer) group.getTag();`

Comment: Your viewholder implementation is not complete, you need to do a settag on each element if convertview !=null