# Android list items are changing when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I have a list that should have each item the same layout except for the first and last item which should have separate layouts. The first item shows its unique layout correctly, but the last one changes when I scroll it in and out of view between the correct one and the layout of the first item. Here is my adapter:

```
public class ListAdapterApp extends ArrayAdapter<App> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<App> appList;

    public ListAdapterApp(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<App> appList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, appList);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.appList = appList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        AppHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {


            holder = new AppHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            if(position == 0){
                holder.rowLayoutID = R.layout.list_column_appheaderitem;
            } else if(position == appList.size() - 1){
                holder.rowLayoutID = R.layout.list_column_appfooteritem;
            } else {
                holder.rowLayoutID = layoutResourceId;
            }
            row = inflater.inflate(holder.rowLayoutID, parent, false);//holder.packBackground = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.packBackground);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (AppHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        App app = appList.get(position);

        return row;
    }

    static class AppHolder
    {
        public int rowLayoutID;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use ViewHolder method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is ListView is recycling a non-footer row view when it calls `getView()` for the last item. You need to implement `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` in your adapter, to give `ListView` a hint about what views can be recycled for those items.

```
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_HEADER = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER = 1;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT = 2;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_COUNT = 3;

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // The total number of row types your adapter supports.
    // This should NEVER change at runtime.
    return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // return a value from zero to (viewTypeCount - 1)
    if (position == 0) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_HEADER;
    } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER;
    }
    return VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT;
}
```

Inside of `getView()` you can call `getItemViewType()` and use a `switch` statement to build your rows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    switch(getItemViewType(position)) {
    case VIEW_TYPE_HEADER:
        return getHeaderView(position, convertView, parent); // TODO implement this
    case VIEW_TYPE_FOOTER:
        return getFooterView(position, convertView, parent); // TODO implement this
    case VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT:
        return getDefaultView(position, convertView, parent); // TODO implement this
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider to still use a viewHolder pattern e.g. in the `getHeaderView, getFooterView` methods to prevent a constant reinflating and redrawing of the layout

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem and then i resolve this issue like don't check `if (row==null)` and then implement else remove the `if else` block and just put the whole code in your `Getview()` Method and then run it your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your `if-else position` checks out side the body of `if(row == null)` like:

```
        if(row == null)
        {
            holder = new AppHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

            row = inflater.inflate(holder.rowLayoutID, parent, false);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (AppHolder)row.getTag();
        }

          if(position == 0){
                holder.rowLayoutID = R.layout.list_column_appheaderitem;
            } else if(position == appList.size() - 1){
                holder.rowLayoutID = R.layout.list_column_appfooteritem;
            } else {
                holder.rowLayoutID = layoutResourceId;
            }
```

Also make `instance of AppHolder` in your `constructor` like:

```
Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    List<App> appList;

AppHolder holder;

    public ListAdapterApp(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<App> appList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, appList);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.appList = appList;

        holder = new AppHolder();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and I solved it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25439793/1216265) . I was facing the problem with RadioGroup and Radio BUttons, but the rest of the problem was similar to your's.