# Large custom listview with radio groups

Tags: android

I am a new android learner. I am working on a project which needs custom List View with 50 or more rows. Each row contains a Text View indicating row numbers and a Radio Group which have four Radio Buttons. Problem is when I check any of the radio buttons and then scroll down, I see many radio buttons automatically checked. And when scroll up I see some random radio button are checked!

I am guessing its happening because of that recycle issue of the getView() method said [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70). Frankly speaking as a novice I couldn't understand the whole lecture.

I have also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392511/how-to-handle-oncheckedchangelistener-for-a-radiogroup-in-a-custom-listview-adap) thread. Which is similar to my problem but couldn't understand clearly and solve my problem.

So how can I solve this problem and get data from the radio groups. As I am a new learner please explain easily.

Thanks!

[[image]Here is my list view with a radio button checked of 1st row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt79K.jpg)

[[image]When I scroll down I see 15th row is auto checked!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGPGu.jpg)

[[image]When scroll up again I see radio group of the 1st row is in initial state again!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkJBU.jpg)

**Here is my code:**

***MainActivity:***

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /* ListView */
    ListView lv;

    /* Data source for numbering */
    String[] numbering = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"};

    /* Custom adapter */
    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* initialization */
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_item, numbering);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvQuestion);

        /* show list view */
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

***list_row_item.xml:***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNumbering"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/answer3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

***Custom List Adapter:***

```java
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    String[] numbers;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
            String[] numbers) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, numbers);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            /* Add layout inflater */
            LayoutInflater infletar = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = infletar.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            /* initialization */
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvNumbering = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvNumbering);
            holder.rg = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

            /* set tag */
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvNumbering.setText(numbers[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvNumbering;
        RadioGroup rg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When `getView` is called you need to initialise the views held in `holder` using the data for the relevant `position`.

You are currently doing this for the `TextView` in the line.

```
holder.tvNumbering.setText(numbers[position]);
```

You need to do the same for the RadioGroup.

At the moment your `CustomListAdapter` is defined as extending an `ArrayAdapter` of `Strings`. So the list of items you past to the adapter is an array of strings, and the only information the adapter holds onto for each item is the value of the ***numbers*** String for each item.

In your case what you really want is for each item to have a ***numbers*** value and a ***checked radio button*** value.

Instead of providing a list of Strings to the adapter, you should provide a list of your own custom class which encapsulates both these variables.

```
public class MyItem {
    public String number;
    public int checkedRadioButtonId;
}
```

You need to make your adapter handle this class.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyItem> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    MyItem[] items;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             MyItem[] items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            // Set a listener to update the data in your items list when the RadioGroup is clicked
            holder.rowRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                    // **get which item this RadioGroup refers to**
                    Integer pos = (Integer) group.getTag();
                    Log.d("onCheckedChanged", "pos = " + pos + ", checkedId = " + checkedId);
                    items[pos].checkedRadioButtonId = checkedId;

                }
            });
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        // **Tag each RadioGroup so we know what item it refers to**
        holder.rowRadioGroup.setTag(position);

        // setup both views from the values stored in your items list
        holder.rowTextView.setText(items[position].number);
        holder.rowRadioGroup.check(items[position].checkedRadioButtonId);



        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView rowTextView = null;
        RadioGroup rowRadioGroup = null;

        ViewHolder(View row) {
            this.rowTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNumbering);
            this.rowRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

Your MainActivity would become something like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /* ListView */
    ListView lv;

    /* Data source for the ListView */
    MyItem[] myItems = new MyItems[50];

    /* Custom adapter */
    CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the data for the list
        for (int i = 0; i < myItems.length; i++) {
            final MyItem item = new MyItem();
            // your numbering goes from 1 to 50, but the array indexes go from 0 to 49
            item.number = String.valueOf(i + 1); 
            // set all items to answer0 by default
            item.checkedRadioButtonId = R.id.answer0

            // put the new item in the array
            myItems[i] = item;
        }

        /* initialization */
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_item, myItems);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvQuestion);

        /* show list view */
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I do that for RadioGroup? In TextView I am passing an information but there is no such thing for RadioGroup!

Comment: Of course there is information for a RadioGroup! You get the information of which button is checked with getCheckedRadioButtonId().

Comment: Most of the errors are gone except, now if I check a radio button and scroll down(so that checked radio button go off screen), then scroll up I see that the checked radio button has gone to its initial state! Why is this happening?

Comment: Sorry. See my latest edit. The OnCheckedChangeListener returns the RadioGroup group that was clicked, but we need to know what item that group referred to. By tagging each group with a position number, we can then extract that info from the `group` object in the listener's onCheckChanged method.

Comment: Hah, one more edit. The tag can be any `object` so when we `getTag()` we need to cast it back to an `Integer` so we can use it.

Comment: I also noticed that when added those two line. But still it causing that issue. After scroll down and then scroll up, checked radio buttons reset to initial state !

Comment: Have updated the CustomListAdapter class. If you look at the source code for [ListView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView), you will see that it caches old item views. It tries to supply the old view back to the adapter as the convertView parameter, so that the adapter can re-use it. Previously we were re-setting the OnCheckChangedListener every time. What we should be doing is only setting it if convertView == null.